How to display respective pdf file on click of a tile in SharePoint Online Modern Page
In SharePoint Online modern page, the requirement is to display respective pdf file dynamically based on click of different tiles/images.
Is there any out of the box way we can achieve this requirement like we were able to do through SharePoint on premise?
Please advise.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Here are steps:
1.In a modern page, insert a Quick Links web part.
2.In the web part, add the pdf file link.
3.In the Thumbnail, choose Custom image.

4.Set Grid layout in the web part.


Thanks for your help. But the pdf files will open in another tab. I used List view webpart and File and Media webpart . I connected the File and Media webpart to the list view webpart. Now it works fine.
Only concern is if I go to the page first time and unless I have selected any of the item from the list view., the file and media webpart is displaying the message 'This web part is connected to Industry Blueprint. Select an item in Industry Blueprint to view it here.'.
So, can we preselect one list item and so that the webpart will display the corresponding pdf by default.

I did a test. There is no option to preselect one list item in the web part.
